# Different hash comes out with fn_md5

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

so i have a very weird issue that its been quite sometime now and am still figuring out why it is is. i have a function in sql server called fn_md5 that accepts 2 parameters and then return it as a varbinary.

but if the function is called via a the php script in my web, the hash is different when you directly call it from the ssms, and all of my ideas are out anymore. all i know is that the fn_md5 function when called directly in the ssms outputs the correct hash that i want it to be.

soo this is my fn_md5 function:

```
    USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[UFN_MD5_ENCODEVALUE]    Script Date: 5/17/2022 4:41:16 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- ЗФјцён : UFN_MD5_ENCODEVALUE()
-- і»їл : ЖЇБ¤№®АЪї­°ъ АОµ¦Ѕєё¦ АМїлЗПї© MD5 °ЄА» »эјє
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_md5]
(
    @btInStr        VARCHAR(10),
    @btInStrIndex       VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS VARBINARY(16)
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @btOutVal   VARBINARY(16)

    EXEC master..XP_MD5_EncodeKeyVal @btInStr, @btInStrIndex, @btOutVal OUT

    RETURN  @btOutVal
END
```

and this is my php script:

```
$xodbc_connect = odbc_connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=WIN-6QBM0ALD4G1\SQLEXPRESS', 'sa', 'superpasszz');
        $statement = "select [dbo].fn_md5('passpass', 'useruser')";
        $exec = odbc_exec($xodbc_connect, $statement);
        $result = odbc_result($exec, 1);
        $password = $result;

        //var_dump($password);

        # insert data
        $data = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'name' => $username,
            'serial' => $this->_defaultAccountSerial,
            'email' => $email
        );
        
        # query
            $query = "INSERT INTO "._TBL_MI_." ("._CLMN_USERNM_.", "._CLMN_PASSWD_.", "._CLMN_MEMBNAME_.", "._CLMN_SNONUMBER_.", "._CLMN_EMAIL_.", "._CLMN_BLOCCODE_.", "._CLMN_CTLCODE_.") VALUES (:username, :password, :name, :serial, :email, 0, 0)";
```

now if i do this script in the ssms:

```
select [dbo].fn_md5('passpass', 'useruser');
```

it will give me this, which should be the correct hash:

```
0x0634DF7B99E2CF2344C3362F8CB76729
```

but if i use the registration process via my web it will give me this instead:

```
0xE5E892FA86C13BB1DF93630458E7DC31
```

the more weirder is that i cannot see what is wrongg and my head is going to blow. am still constantly learning both languages please bare with me and i hope you can help me out :<

Comment: Aside from the specific question...are you using this function to hash passwords? MD5 is insecure, you cannot rely on it to secure a password anymore. This has been the case for quite a few years now, due to advances in hardware - it's easy to crack with brute force.

Comment: hi @ADyson, thank you for editing my post yes we are using md5 still for an old game. but im kinda stuck with it.

Comment: I see. Any reason you don't use the Hashbytes function in T-SQL to do that? It can generate valid MD5. Anyway I cannot think of a reason why the function would behave differently when called from ODBC, except if somehow the text is transformed before it reaches the server (but that would be surprising) or if you have some hidden characters in there (try deleting the values from your code and typing them entirely by hand if you didn't already). Either that or you're not executing the version of the PHP code that you think you are. After that I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: hi again adyson, thank you for your reply. yes, ive already tried that aswell. i know i can get this fixed i just need to dig a little and push myself more. im trying to fix this by after getting enough sleep and figure it out again and do another way in executing the code.

Comment: `[dbo].fn_md5('passpass', 'useruser')` this pretty much looks like a userdefined function, stored in the database... only god and the coder knows, what it might look like. Why does it take 2 parameters? How looks the implementation, what does it _actually_ do?

Comment: The fn_md5 function is included in my post and what it outputs when passed by 2 varchar parameters.